# Firebase - Geofire and Cloud Functions. Does end of function means no more listeners?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, geofire

In my cloud functions's `index.js` file, I have the following function body:

```
exports.onSuggestionCreated = functions.firestore.document('suggestions/{userId}').onCreate(event => {

    return admin.firestore().doc(`places/settings/profile`).get().then(doc => {

        [...]

        const location = data.location

        const ref = admin.database().ref(`suggestion_locations`)
        const geoFire = new GeoFire(ref)

        var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
            center: [location.latitude, location.longitude],
            radius: 1.0
        })

        geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
           return sendMessageTo(key, title, body)
        })
    })
})
```

This is inside a function that is triggered whenever something is created.

What I would to know is, is the "key_entered" called every time something enters the region delimited by location and radius of `GeoFire` even though the cloud function has long been terminated? I got some strange logs that indicate so.

Given the asynchronous nature of `GeoFire`, what could I do in this situation?

Comment: GeoFire won't work well within Cloud Functions without either modifications or extra care. Your code doesn't show the type of Cloud Function you use, so it's hard to recommend anything beyond what I just wrote.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, see my edit please.

Comment: Thanks for the update. [Cloud Functions can run at most 9 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas), so there's simply nothing you can do beyond that. In fact, background functions (such as functions triggered from Firestore) default to a maximum of 60 seconds. Given the nature of Cloud Functions, I'd stick to their trigger-do-something-and-exit approach. Given that: what would you like to do when a suggestion document is written? E.g.: if you want to know all keys that are **currently** within range, that is achievable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoFire relies on [keeping active listeners on the geodata](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/src/geoQuery.js#L305-L307) that is within range. This does not match with Cloud Functions' run-and-exit paradigm.

The concepts (storing lat+lon in geohashes and running range queries on that) work fine, but you may have to modify the library or pay attention to its implementation details to make it work in your situation.

The best seems to be to return for example all locations that are currently within a given area. This can be done by listening to the `key_entered` event (as you already do) *and* to the `ready` event, which [fires after the initial `key_entered` calls have been received](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoqueryoneventtype-callback).

```
exports.onSuggestionCreated = functions.firestore.document('suggestions/{userId}').onCreate(event => {

  return admin.firestore().doc(`places/settings/profile`).get().then(doc => {
    [...]

    const location = data.location

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const ref = admin.database().ref(`suggestion_locations`)
        const geoFire = new GeoFire(ref)

        var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
            center: [location.latitude, location.longitude],
            radius: 1.0
        })

        geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
           sendMessageTo(key, title, body)
        })
        geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
            resolve();
        });
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks so much for all your helpful answers and talks on YouTube! If I wanted to get all the locations in JSON format using the cloud function, should I create an array, append new locations in `geoQuery.on` and then return the array inside `resolve()`?

Comment: Thank you. I'm able to fetch all the locations and enter the `on("ready"` state, however it looks like the cloud function isn't returning anything and times out. Should I use `res.send(array)` after `resolve(array)`?

Comment: This Cloud Function is triggered by a write to Firestore. There's no way to return something meaningful here, as nobody is listening to it. I recommend opening a new question with your specific use-case, and the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).