# Using GeoFire with Firebase Cloud Functions and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a Firebase Cloud Function to fetch locations close to a certain geographical point ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100433/firebase-geofire-and-cloud-functions-does-end-of-function-means-no-more-liste)). This function accepts two arguments: latitude and longitude.

```js
export const getDrinkingFountains = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const latitude = req.query.latitude;
  const longitude = req.query.longitude;

  const ref = admin.database().ref("Fountains");
  const geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
  // const keys: Fountain[] = {};

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const geoQuery = geoFire.query({
      center: [latitude, longitude],
      radius: 10.0
    });

    geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
      // var fountain: Fountain = {key: key, latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude, distance: distance};
      // keys.push(fountain);
    });

    geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
      resolve(arrayShouldGoHere);
    });
  });
});
```

My problem is that it looks like:

- I'm not correctly parsing the latitude and longitude from the request. In fact, GeoFire complains `Error: Invalid GeoFire location '40,40': latitude must be a number`. Using Postman I'm actually just passing two integers with no string literals.
- I don't know how to create an array of Fountains. I'm not comfortable with TypeScript.

Any hints?

Comment: it looks like your latitude is coming in the form of `40,40` instead of a number. if you log `latitude` and `longitude` whats the value?

Comment: @C_Ogoo By printing it out I get `Latitude is 40 and longitude: 40` which looks correct. Maybe TypeScript infers the type and turns them into strings?

Comment: then potentially a location at this document `const ref = admin.database().ref('Fountains')` has an incorrect value

Comment: Typescript is only at compile time .. during runtime there isnt any type checking or inferencing

Comment: it turns out checking `typeof` on latitude and longitude returns `string`. I'm not sure how I should go about "fixing" it

Comment: ahh, now the error makes sense .. check my answer for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `latitude` and `longitude` to a number using the [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) class

```js
const latitude = Number(req.query.latitude);
const longitude = Number(req.query.longitude);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Now, let's get that array thing fixed.